# Silently print a PDF file using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, printing, blob

The thing I want to build is that by clicking a button I want to trigger the direct print of a PDF file, but without opening or viewing it.

I have PDF as blob file returned from fetch API.

I tried a lot of examples but don't know exactly how to do it

Some examples tried:

```js
// In my case, I had only blobData from PDF, but you can ignore this and set fileURL directly if it is not yours.
const file = new Blob([blobData], { type: 'application/pdf' });
const fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);

// As the URL is dynamic, we must set src here, but if it's not, just leave it direct on the HTML. 
// Also, be careful with React literals. If you do this in a <iframe> defined in JSX, it won't work 
// as React will keep src property undefined.
window.frames["my-frame"].src = fileURL;

// Then print:
window.frames["my-frame"].print();
```

```html
<iframe name="my-frame" id="my-frame" title="my-frame" style="display: none"></iframe>
```

Also tried library, Print.js: http://printjs.crabbly.com/.

Is there way to print the pdf without visually opening it to the user?
We should support only Chrome browser.

Can someone provide example how to do it in React, Redux application?

Comment: Check if this is helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135387/how-to-print-react-component-on-click-of-a-button. it has github link to the code files check them as well.

Comment: Thanks, i will try.

Comment: This won't work for me, it kinda should look like this example [stackoverflow.com/questions/46125045](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46125045/printing-a-pdf-directly-using-javascript)

Comment: Why this more than weird requirement of not showing the pdf? As a user, I always want to see what I'll print, you're not going to make me print a 500 colored pages comic. Toner is not cheap.

Comment: It is a requirement and user that uses this app knows what he is printing ant PDF file contains only one page.

Comment: @user1990 , did you resolved silently print issue?

Comment: @Kaiido If there's a list of files to print and you don't want user to confirm every print popup

Comment: @CDT then merge in a single multi page pdf.

Answer (score 1):

try this [print-js](https://printjs.crabbly.com/) and [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/print-js) is npm package

install npm package

```
npm install print-js --save
```

Add following code

```
import print from "print-js";

const fileURL = "someurl.com/document.pdf"; 

const handlePrint = (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();
    print(fileURL);

};
```

similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74966201/how-to-print-pdf-file-silently-in-reactjs/74996837#74996837)