# How to Print PDF file silently in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
const pdfURL = "someurl.com/document.pdf";
const handlePrint = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const win: Window | null = window.open(pdfURL);
        if (win) {
            win.onload = () => {
                win.print();
            };
        }
    };
```

above code opens PDF file into new tab and then print but I want to print directly without opening it into a new tab.

Comment: You can replace current page with the pdf and then go back probably

Comment: @Konrad what do you mean by "replace current page with the pdf"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install npm package

```
npm install print-js --save
```

Add following code

```
import print from "print-js";

const pdfURL = "someurl.com/document.pdf"; 

const handlePrint = (e: React.FormEvent) => {

    e.preventDefault();
    print(pdfURL);

};
```

Comment: using print-js is still showing print preview from browser

Comment: did you find any solution @Norris

Comment: @Skandkumar I'm using google chrome silent print / kiosk print

Comment: can you send me provide me some link or code