# React component loses formatting related to className when printing triggered from button, but keeps it when done inline

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, printing

The issue of React and printing has stopped me in my tracks for the last week and half and I don't feel like I am getting anywhere.

I found this helpful SO, but none of the solutions work completely for me:

[How to print React component on click of a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135387/how-to-print-react-component-on-click-of-a-button/?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

The result is basically the same each time: styles are not being reflected when you click the "Print" button and it brings you to print dialog. I have pretty much exhausted any option and configuration I can think of.

Here is my repo regarding the issue:

https://github.com/ishraqiyun77/react-print-iframe-issue

In the example, I'm just trying to turn the text red with `color: red`. This formatting is reflected on screen, but goes away when the "Print" button is clicked and the print preview comes up. It should not be doing this. `@media print` doesn't affect it.

The "Print" button has to function properly as opposed to just printing in browser or `CTRL + P` due to many of our users not being savvy... at all.

The repo includes a modified version of `bootstrap.css` that has all of the `@media print` removed.

So what is going on here and why are styles from an external file that are assigned via `className` not working, but inline CSS is working? Any help is appreciated. (Inline is not an option since it will be a mess).

```
// component.jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {
    Button,
    Modal,
    ModalBody,
    ModalHeader
} from 'reactstrap';

import styles from '../assets/scss/app.scss';

class TestPrint extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            modal: false,
            data: [
                'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test',
                'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test',
                'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test',
                'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test',
                'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test',
                'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test',
                'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test',
                'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test'
            ]
        }
        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
        this.print = this.print.bind(this);
    }

    print() {
        var content = document.getElementById('printarea');
        var pri = document.getElementById('ifmcontentstoprint').contentWindow;
        pri.document.open();
        pri.document.write(content.innerHTML);
        pri.document.close();
        pri.focus();
        pri.print();
    }

    renderContent() {
        var i = 0;
        return this.state.data.map((d) => {
            i++
            return (<p className='printtest' key={i}>{i} - {d}</p>)
        });
    }

    toggle() {
        this.setState({
            modal: !this.state.modal
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Button
                    style={
                        {
                            position: 'fixed',
                            top: '50%',
                            left: '50%',
                            transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)'
                        }
                    }
                    onClick={this.toggle}
                >
                    Test Modal and Print
                </Button>
                <Modal
                    size='lg'
                    isOpen={this.state.modal}
                    toggle={this.toggle}
                    className='results-modal'
                >
                    <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>
                        Test Printing
                        </ModalHeader>
                    <iframe id="ifmcontentstoprint" style={{
                        height: '0px',
                        width: '0px',
                        position: 'absolute',
                    }}></iframe>
                    <Button onClick={this.print}>Print</Button>
                    <ModalBody id='printarea'>
                        {this.renderContent()}
                    </ModalBody>
                </Modal>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TestPrint />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

---

```
.printtest {
    color: red !important;
}
```

Then if you change the `renderContent()` method to the following, the styles do work in printing (but again is undesirable as it will be a mess):

```
renderContent() {
    var i = 0;
    return this.state.data.map((d) => {
        i++
        return (<p style={{ color: 'red' }} key={i}>{i} - {d}</p>)
    });
}
```

**EDIT**

And I have tried `CTRL + P`, printing from browser, printing window with JS, and using CSS like the following:

```
@media print {
    body * {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .printtest, .printtest* {
        visibility: visible;
    }

    .printtest {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        overflow: scroll/visible/auto;
    }
}
```

The problem with this though is it only prints one page and what is currently on the screen, not all the data loaded into the modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building off of what Al Farnsworth suggested, I had to do the following and now it works:

```
    var content = document.getElementById('print');
    var pri = document.getElementById('ifmcontentstoprint').contentWindow;
    pri.document.open();
    pri.document.write(content.innerHTML);

    // generate CSS links
    var bootstrap = document.createElement('link');
    bootstrap.href = '/static/css/bootstrap.css';
    bootstrap.rel = 'stylesheet';
    pri.document.head.appendChild(bootstrap);

    var app = document.createElement('link');
    app.href = '/static/css/bq_print.css';
    app.rel = 'stylesheet';
    pri.document.head.appendChild(app);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your example, I don't see any CSS included inside your iframe.  Styles from the parent document do not apply to elements inside an `<iframe>`.  If you want that, you'll need to manually insert the CSS links in the iframe.

You should be able to see what's happening by just making the frame and inspecting with devtools.  Take the width:0 height,:0 off.  I have a feeling you'll see that even the on-screen version is missing css syles.

Comment: Correct, CSS isn't inherited from the parent and it isn't taking the class/id level styles that are being passed into the `<iframe>`. So the question is how do I correctly pass in the CSS?