# window.print() shows the same result on different pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome

I am trying to print some bills with **window.print()** function in JavaScript. I am using React.js for it and when I click **Print** it prints what it needs. After that, if I want to print another bill, it is showing the data from the first one I tried to print. Doesn't matter how many different bills I try to print, it always shows the data from the first one I tried to print. The only solution I found is to reload the page, but then I need to log in again, and I am loosing the state of application.

Is there any way how can I restart that window.print() function not to take data from previous prints?

Below is code sample that does printing

```
 printElement(elem) {
    var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);

    var $printSection = document.getElementById("printSection");

    if (!$printSection) {
        var $printSection = document.createElement("div");
        $printSection.id = "printSection";
        document.body.appendChild($printSection);
    }

    $printSection.innerHTML = "";
    $printSection.appendChild(domClone);
    window.print();
    window.close();
}

print() {
    this.printElement(document.getElementById("divToPrint"));
}
```

Comment: How about a [mcve]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30137174/4925008 this answer might help you, either use document to be filled then print, or use iframes

Comment: Maybe you're getting the same `divToPrint` every time. You'll have to debug by looking at what variables you're assigning and when they're getting reassigned or getting new data. It could even be that when a div is hidden, it's still in the DOM and thus `getElementById` is grabbing the first one every time.

Answer (score 0):

The DOM is not updated by the time the print function is executed, allow a momentary delay.

```
printElement(elem) {
    var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);

    var $printSection = document.getElementById("printSection");

    if (!$printSection) {
        var $printSection = document.createElement("div");
        $printSection.id = "printSection";
        document.body.appendChild($printSection);
    }

    $printSection.innerHTML = "";
    $printSection.appendChild(domClone);

    // Small delay of 0.5s
    setTimeout(() => {
        window.print();
        window.close();
    }, 500);

}
```

Comment: It does not work, I even tried with 5000ms delay to give it a time, but it does not work. By the way, when I select the bill to print, the state updates, and I have a correct state that should be printed, but I have a feeling that somehow the first data is stored and that I need to clear it. And the only way so far is by refreshing which does not do the job for me

Comment: Hm, my other suggestion would be to try a helper extension, such as http://printjs.crabbly.com/