# How to store the html return of a react component in a variable

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to store the return of a react component in a variable so I can later use it to implement a search of the variable content:
For example:

```
const myComponent = (props) => (
<div><span>my name is  {props.name}</span></div>
```

)

then I would like to do the following:

```
const resultForSearch = <myComponent name="bob"/>
console.log(resultForSearch ) // would be : my name is  bob
```

Comment: I think this will solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135387/how-to-print-react-component-on-click-of-a-button

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print React component on click of a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135387/how-to-print-react-component-on-click-of-a-button)