# change state before and after print for displaying only on print

Tags: reactjs

Tested with browser Chrome (version 84.0.4147.125)

**What I am trying to do:**

To get the student's `<h2>name</h2>` to appear at the top only when print is clicked, after the print modal goes away(print/save/cancel) the state should return back to the way it was.(students `<h2>name</h2>` should be hidden at the top again.)

**The full code:** https://codesandbox.io/s/pagination-tables-print-demo-59u37

**The Tables Page:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet'

// Components
import StudentStudyDetails from '../Components/TablesPage/StudentStudyDetails.js';

// Test Data
import { johnDoeTwoWeeks } from '../Tests/index.js';

const Tables = () => {
  const [inPrintPreview, setInPrintPreview] = useState(false);

  const print = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();

    Promise.resolve(setInPrintPreview(true))
      .then(() => {
        let printContents = document.getElementById("print-report-student-div").innerHTML;
        let originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
        document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
        window.print();
        document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
      })
  }

  return (
    <div className="page-container">
      <Helmet>
          <title>Tables-Demo</title>
          <meta name="description" content="Nested component" />
      </Helmet>
      <h1 className="h1-reports-title">Tables</h1>
      <div>
        {<button type="button" onClick={ev => print(ev)} className="btn-reports-submit">Print</button>}
        {<StudentStudyDetails tableData={johnDoeTwoWeeks} inPrintPreview={inPrintPreview} />}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Tables;
```

---

The Table Component:

```
import React from 'react';

// Globals
import { reportsBackendResponses, reportsBackendAttendence } from '../../Globals/index.js';

const StudentReportTable = props => {
  const { tableData, reportElement, inPrintPreview } = props;
  return (
    <div id="print-report-student-div" className="div-reports-tbl">
      <h2 className={inPrintPreview ? "h2-print-title-name": "display-none"}>{tableData.lastName},&nbsp;{tableData.firstName}</h2>
      <table id="print-report-student-table-center" className="tbl-reports">
        <tbody>
          <tr className="tbl-reports-header-row">
            <th>Week&nbsp;ending:<br />{tableData.weeks[reportElement].weekEnding}</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th colSpan="2">Teacher:<br />{tableData.tutorName}</th>
            <th>{tableData.weeks[reportElement].weekTotalHours}</th>
          </tr>
          <tr className="tbl-reports-title-row">
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Response</th>
            <th>Tutor Hours</th>
            <th>Credit Value</th>
            <th>Attendence</th>
            <th>Study Value</th>
            <th>Total</th>
          </tr>
          {tableData.weeks[reportElement].daysInfo.map((row, index) => 
            <tr key={index} className="tbl-reports-record-row">
              <td>{row.dayDate}</td>
              <td>
                {row.response.toLowerCase() === reportsBackendResponses.notAsked ? 
                  <p className="p-reports-not-asked">{row.response}</p> : 
                  (row.response.toLowerCase() === reportsBackendResponses.worked ?
                    <p className="p-reports-worked">{row.response}</p> : 
                    (row.response.toLowerCase() === reportsBackendResponses.absent ?
                      <p className="p-reports-absent">{row.response}</p> : 
                      (row.response.toLowerCase() === reportsBackendResponses.refused ?
                        <p className="p-reports-refused">{row.response}</p> :
                        <p className="p-reports-default">{row.response}</p>
                      )
                    )
                  )
                }
              </td>
              <td>{row.tutorHours}</td>
              <td>{row.creditValue}</td>
              <td>
                {row.attendence.toLowerCase() === reportsBackendAttendence.cancelled ? 
                  <p className="p-reports-cancelled">{row.attendence}</p> : 
                  (row.attendence.toLowerCase() === reportsBackendAttendence.present ?
                    <p className="p-reports-present">{row.attendence}</p> : 
                    (row.attendence.toLowerCase() === reportsBackendAttendence.noShow ?
                      <p className="p-reports-no-show">{row.attendence}</p> : 
                      (row.attendence.toLowerCase() === reportsBackendAttendence.notPlanned ?
                        <p className="p-reports-not-planned">{row.attendence}</p> :
                        <p className="p-reports-default">{row.attendence}</p>
                      )
                    )
                  )
                }
              </td>
              {row.studyValue ? <td>{row.studyValue}</td> : <td style={{color: "#CCCCCC"}}>-&nbsp;-&nbsp;-</td>}
              <td>{row.totalDayHours}</td>
            </tr>
          )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  )
}

export default StudentReportTable;
```

---

**The CSS:**

```
/*---------------------------------------- Globals ----------------------------------------*/
html,
body,
#root {
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  min-height: 100% !important;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
    'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  overflow: auto!important;
}
* {
box-sizing: inherit !important;
}
*:before, *:after {
box-sizing: inherit !important;
}
code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, 'Courier New',
    monospace;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
  margin: 0;
}
footer {
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 2em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-top: 4em;
}

@media print {
  html, body {
    height: initial !important;
    overflow: initial !important;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  }
}

@media print {
  #print-report-student-table-center {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:15;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -462px; /* half of table width size */
  }
}

@page {
  size: auto;
  margin-top: 20mm;
}
/*---------------------------------------- General ----------------------------------------*/
.absolute-bottom-left {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.z-index-5 {
  z-index: 5;
}
.position-relative {
  position: relative;
}
.overflow-hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.display-none {
  display: none;
}
/*---------------------------------------- Classes ----------------------------------------*/
.app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.btn-pagination-selected-tab {
  width: 60px;
  background-color: #01A3E0;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 12px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.btn-pagination-unselected-tab {
  width: 60px;
  background-color: #85C8E9;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 12px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.btn-pagination-unselected-tab:hover {
  background-color: #4AB0E1;
}
.btn-reports-submit {
  background-color: #01A3E0;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 2px solid #01A3E0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
  outline: none!important;
  box-shadow: none!important;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  float: right;
}
.btn-reports-submit:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: #01A3E0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.btn-reports-submit:active {
  background-color: #01A3E0;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.div-pagination {
  display: flex;
  user-select: none;
}
.div-reports-details-container {
  display: block;
  max-width: 950px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
.div-reports-student {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
.div-reports-student-container {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 68px;
}
.div-reports-student-photo-name {
  border-top: 2px solid #DDDDDD;
  border-right: 2px solid #DDDDDD;
  border-left: 2px solid #DDDDDD;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px 70px;
}
.div-reports-student-photo-name img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.div-reports-student-photo-name p {
  margin: 30px 0 0;
  color: #01A3E0;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.div-reports-student-total {
  border-right: 2px solid #01A3E0;
  background-color: #01A3E0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
.div-reports-tbl {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px;
}
.h1-reports-title {
  margin: 10px 0 20px;
}
.h2-print-title-name {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
.header a {
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.p-reports-not-asked {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0;
  background-color: #FFEDBC;
  border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.p-reports-worked {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0;
  background-color: #CBFCCB;
  border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.p-reports-absent {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0;
  background-color: #FBC7C5;
  border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.p-reports-refused {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0;
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
  border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.p-reports-cancelled {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: #FFEDBC;
  border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.p-reports-present {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: #CBFCCB;
  border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.p-reports-no-show {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: #FBC7C5;
  border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.p-reports-not-planned {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.p-reports-default {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.page-container {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.pages-container {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
}
.tbl-reports {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-collapse: separate; /* Don't collapse */
  border-spacing: 0;
  text-align: left;
}
.tbl-reports-header-row th {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #01A3E0;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-top: 2px solid #01A3E0;
}
.tbl-reports-header-row th:first-child {
  width: 140px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-left: 2px solid #01A3E0;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.tbl-reports-header-row th:nth-child(2) {
  width: 140px;
}
.tbl-reports-header-row th:nth-child(3) {
  width: 90px;
}
.tbl-reports-header-row th:nth-child(4) {
  width: 120px;
}
.tbl-reports-header-row th:nth-child(5) {
  width: 155px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: end;
}
.tbl-reports-header-row th:nth-child(6) {
  width: 140px;
}
.tbl-reports-header-row th:last-child {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-right: 2px solid #01A3E0;
  border-left: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
  width: 110px;
  text-align: end;
}
.tbl-reports-title-row th {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #EBF6FC;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.tbl-reports-title-row th:first-child {
  width: 140px;
  border-left: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.tbl-reports-title-row th:nth-child(2) {
  width: 140px;
}
.tbl-reports-title-row th:nth-child(3) {
  width: 90px;
}
.tbl-reports-title-row th:nth-child(4) {
  width: 120px;
}
.tbl-reports-title-row th:nth-child(5) {
  width: 155px;
}
.tbl-reports-title-row th:nth-child(6) {
  width: 140px;
}
.tbl-reports-title-row th:last-child {
  border-right: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-left: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
  width: 110px;
  text-align: end;
}
.tbl-reports-record-row {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
}
.tbl-reports-record-row td {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
}
.tbl-reports-record-row:last-child td {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.tbl-reports-record-row td:first-child {
  border-left: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.tbl-reports-record-row td:not(:first-child) {
  text-align: center;
}
.tbl-reports-record-row td:nth-child(5) {
  text-align: left;
}
.tbl-reports-record-row td:nth-child(6) {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
.tbl-reports-record-row td:last-child {
  border-right: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-left: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
  text-align: end;
}
```

---

I'm new with handling state during print outs, so any help would be much appreciated.

My guess is the change would need to be somewhere in this snippet:

```
    Promise.resolve(setInPrintPreview(true))
      .then(() => {
        let printContents = document.getElementById("print-report-student-div").innerHTML;
        let originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
        document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
        window.print();
        document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
      })
```

**Note:** I also noticed an issue where the pagination stops working after the print modal goes away, which tells me javascript is getting hung up on something.

Comment: React does not play nicely with changes to the underlying DOM. If you inspect the buttons before and after clicking print, you can see that the event listeners are all being stripped out. The VDOM has lost all the context it needs to render changes. I've never tried something like this before so I don't know what the solution is, but you're going to have to go about it in the 'React' way. I see there are libraries for print functionality out there that may point you in the right direction.

Comment: hmmm thanks, yeah my work is very strict about using 3rd party libraries they haven't approved yet (such as `react-to-print` and `react-print`). I'm going to try fiddling around more with the first solution from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135387/how-to-print-react-component-on-click-of-a-button (even though I wasn't successful on the first attempt).

Comment: Looks like this is a known issue > https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/16734
(seems odd it's been over 5 years with react and they are just now recognizing this with a basic feature such as print)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution requires the use of a 3rd party library and has the constraint of not being able to use react hooks with the component (because it must be a class component), but it works...

### Solution

**The full code:** https://codesandbox.io/s/pagination-tables-print-demo-v3-yej7k

Tables.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";

// Components
import StudentStudyDetails from "../Components/TablesPage/StudentStudyDetails.js";

// Test Data
import { johnDoeTwoWeeks } from "../Tests/index.js";

const Tables = () => {

  return (
    <div className="page-container">
      <Helmet>
        <title>Tables-Demo</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Nested component" />
      </Helmet>
      <h1 className="h1-reports-title">Tables</h1>
      <div>
        <StudentStudyDetails
          tableData={johnDoeTwoWeeks}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Tables;
```

StudentStudyDetails.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Photo from "../../img/photo.png";
import ReactToPrint from "react-to-print";

// Globals
import { getAvailablePaginatedTabs } from "../../Globals/index.js";

// Components
import StudentReportTable from "./StudentReportTable.js";
import PaginationTabs from "../Shared/PaginationTabs.js";

class StudentStudyDetails extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedPaginationTab: 1,
      inPrintPreview: false
    }
  }

  setSelectedPaginationTab = (tabNum) => {
    this.setState({...this.state, selectedPaginationTab: tabNum});
  }

  setInPrintPreview(status){
    this.setState({...this.state, inPrintPreview: status});
  }
  
  render(){
    const { inPrintPreview, selectedPaginationTab } = this.state;
    const { tableData } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <ReactToPrint
          onBeforeGetContent={() => this.setInPrintPreview(true)}
          trigger={() => <button type="button" className="btn-reports-submit">Print</button>}
          content={() => this.componentRef}
          onAfterPrint={() => this.setInPrintPreview(false)}
        />
        <div className="div-reports-student">
          <div className="div-reports-details-container">
            <PaginationTabs
              setSelectedPaginationTab={this.setSelectedPaginationTab}
              selectedPaginationTab={selectedPaginationTab}
              pages={getAvailablePaginatedTabs(
                tableData.weeks.length,
                selectedPaginationTab
              )}
              lastPage={tableData.weeks.length}
            />
            <StudentReportTable
              tableData={tableData}
              reportElement={selectedPaginationTab - 1}
              inPrintPreview={inPrintPreview}
              ref={el => (this.componentRef = el)}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="div-reports-student-container">
            <div className="div-reports-student-photo-name">
              <img src={Photo} alt="student" />
              <p>
                {tableData.firstName}&nbsp;{tableData.lastName}
              </p>
            </div>
            <div className="div-reports-student-total">
              <h5>Year&nbsp;Total:&nbsp;{tableData.yearTotalHours}</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default StudentStudyDetails;
```

StudentReportTable.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

// Globals
import {
  reportsBackendResponses,
  reportsBackendAttendence
} from "../../Globals/index.js";

class StudentReportTable extends Component {
  render(){
    const {inPrintPreview, reportElement, tableData} = this.props;
    return (
      <div id="print-report-student-div" className="div-reports-tbl">
        <h2 className={inPrintPreview ? "h2-print-title-name" : "display-none"}>
          {tableData.lastName},&nbsp;{tableData.firstName}
        </h2>
        <table id="print-report-student-table-center" className="tbl-reports">
          <tbody>
            <tr className="tbl-reports-header-row">
              <th>
                Week&nbsp;ending:
                <br />
                {tableData.weeks[reportElement].weekEnding}
              </th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th colSpan="2">
                Teacher:
                <br />
                {tableData.tutorName}
              </th>
              <th>{tableData.weeks[reportElement].weekTotalHours}</th>
            </tr>
            <tr className="tbl-reports-title-row">
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Response</th>
              <th>Tutor Hours</th>
              <th>Credit Value</th>
              <th>Attendence</th>
              <th>Study Value</th>
              <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
            {tableData.weeks[reportElement].daysInfo.map((row, index) => (
              <tr key={index} className="tbl-reports-record-row">
                <td>{row.dayDate}</td>
                <td>
                  {row.response.toLowerCase() ===
                  reportsBackendResponses.notAsked ? (
                    <p className="p-reports-not-asked">{row.response}</p>
                  ) : row.response.toLowerCase() ===
                    reportsBackendResponses.worked ? (
                    <p className="p-reports-worked">{row.response}</p>
                  ) : row.response.toLowerCase() ===
                    reportsBackendResponses.absent ? (
                    <p className="p-reports-absent">{row.response}</p>
                  ) : row.response.toLowerCase() ===
                    reportsBackendResponses.refused ? (
                    <p className="p-reports-refused">{row.response}</p>
                  ) : (
                    <p className="p-reports-default">{row.response}</p>
                  )}
                </td>
                <td>{row.tutorHours}</td>
                <td>{row.creditValue}</td>
                <td>
                  {row.attendence.toLowerCase() ===
                  reportsBackendAttendence.cancelled ? (
                    <p className="p-reports-cancelled">{row.attendence}</p>
                  ) : row.attendence.toLowerCase() ===
                    reportsBackendAttendence.present ? (
                    <p className="p-reports-present">{row.attendence}</p>
                  ) : row.attendence.toLowerCase() ===
                    reportsBackendAttendence.noShow ? (
                    <p className="p-reports-no-show">{row.attendence}</p>
                  ) : row.attendence.toLowerCase() ===
                    reportsBackendAttendence.notPlanned ? (
                    <p className="p-reports-not-planned">{row.attendence}</p>
                  ) : (
                    <p className="p-reports-default">{row.attendence}</p>
                  )}
                </td>
                {row.studyValue ? (
                  <td>{row.studyValue}</td>
                ) : (
                  <td style={{ color: "#CCCCCC" }}>-&nbsp;-&nbsp;-</td>
                )}
                <td>{row.totalDayHours}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default StudentReportTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution solves both problems the original op is having, but introduces two new problems I don't know how to solve...

---

### Solution

**The full code:** https://codesandbox.io/s/pagination-tables-print-demo-59u37

Tables.js

```
  const print = ev => {
    ev.preventDefault();

    Promise.resolve(setInPrintPreview(true)).then(() => {
      let printContents = document.getElementById("print-report-student-div");
      let pri;
      if (document.getElementById("ifmcontentstoprint")) {
        pri = document.getElementById("ifmcontentstoprint").contentWindow;
      } else {
        const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        iframe.setAttribute("title", "ifmcontentstoprint");
        iframe.setAttribute("id", "ifmcontentstoprint");
        iframe.setAttribute(
          "style",
          "height: 0px; width: 0px; position: absolute;"
        );
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        pri = iframe.contentWindow;
      }
      pri.document.open();
      pri.document.write(printContents.innerHTML);
      pri.document.close();
      pri.focus();
      pri.print();
      setInPrintPreview(false);
    });
  };
```

now using this library does not respect the css, so we have to add inline styling.

StudentReportTable.js

```
  return (
    <div
      id="print-report-student-div"
      style={{ width: "100%", marginTop: "20px" }}
    >
      <h2
        style={
          inPrintPreview
            ? { textAlign: "center", marginBottom: "40px" }
            : { display: "none" }
        }
      >
        {tableData.lastName},&nbsp;{tableData.firstName}
      </h2>
      <table
        id="print-report-student-table-center"
        style={{
          borderBottom: "2px solid #cccccc",
          borderCollapse: "separate",
          borderSpacing: "0",
          textAlign: "left"
        }}
      >
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th
              style={{
                position: "sticky",
                top: "0",
                width: "140px",
                backgroundColor: "#01a3e0",
                color: "#ffffff",
                borderLeft: "2px solid #01a3e0",
                padding: "10px 20px 10px 30px",
                fontSize: "18px",
                borderTop: "2px solid #01a3e0"
              }}
            >
              Week&nbsp;ending:
              <br />
              {tableData.weeks[reportElement].weekEnding}
            </th>
            <th
              style={{
                position: "sticky",
                top: "0",
                width: "140px",
                backgroundColor: "#01a3e0",
                padding: "10px 20px",
                fontSize: "18px",
                borderTop: "2px solid #01a3e0"
              }}
            />
            <th
              style={{
                position: "sticky",
                top: "0",
                width: "90px",
                backgroundColor: "#01a3e0",
                padding: "10px 20px",
                fontSize: "18px",
                borderTop: "2px solid #01a3e0"
              }}
            />
            <th
              style={{
                position: "sticky",
                top: "0",
                width: "120px",
                backgroundColor: "#01a3e0",
                padding: "10px 20px",
                fontSize: "18px",
                borderTop: "2px solid #01a3e0"
              }}
            />
            <th
              style={{
                position: "sticky",
                top: "0",
                width: "155px",
                backgroundColor: "#01a3e0",
                color: "#ffffff",
                textAlign: "end",
                padding: "10px 20px",
                fontSize: "18px",
                borderTop: "2px solid #01a3e0"
              }}
              colSpan="2"
            >
              Teacher:
              <br />
              {tableData.tutorName}
            </th>
            <th
              style={{
                position: "sticky",
                top: "0",
                width: "110px",
                backgroundColor: "#01a3e0",
                color: "#ffffff",
                borderRight: "2px solid #01a3e0",
                borderLeft: "2px solid #cccccc",
                textAlign: "end",
                padding: "10px 20px",
                fontSize: "18px",
                borderTop: "2px solid #01a3e0"
              }}
            >
              {tableData.weeks[reportElement].weekTotalHours}
            </th>
          </tr>
          <tr className="tbl-reports-title-row">
            <th
              style={{
                position: "sticky",
                top: "0",
                width: "140px",
                padding: "10px 20px 10px 30px",
                backgroundColor: "#ebf6fc",
                fontSize: "18px",
                borderLeft: "2px solid #cccccc"
              }}
            >
              Date
            </th>
            <th
              style={{
                position: "sticky",
                top: "0",
                width: "140px",
                padding: "10px 20px",
                backgroundColor: "#ebf6fc",
                fontSize: "18px"
              }}
            >
              Response
            </th>
            <th
              style={{
                position: "sticky",
                top: "0",
                width: "90px",
                padding: "10px 20px",
                backgroundColor: "#ebf6fc",
                fontSize: "18px"
              }}
            >
              Tutor Hours
            </th>
            <th
              style={{
                position: "sticky",
                top: "0",
                width: "120px",
                padding: "10px 20px",
                backgroundColor: "#ebf6fc",
                fontSize: "18px"
              }}
            >
              Credit Value
            </th>
            <th
              style={{
                position: "sticky",
                top: "0",
                width: "155px",
                padding: "10px 20px",
                backgroundColor: "#ebf6fc",
                fontSize: "18px"
              }}
            >
              Attendence
            </th>
            <th
              style={{
                position: "sticky",
                top: "0",
                width: "140px",
                padding: "10px 20px",
                backgroundColor: "#ebf6fc",
                fontSize: "18px"
              }}
            >
              Study Value
            </th>
            <th
              style={{
                position: "sticky",
                top: "0",
                width: "110px",
                padding: "10px 20px",
                backgroundColor: "#ebf6fc",
                fontSize: "18px",
                borderRight: "2px solid #cccccc",
                borderLeft: "2px solid #cccccc",
                textAlign: "end"
              }}
            >
              Total
            </th>
          </tr>
          {tableData.weeks[reportElement].daysInfo.map((row, index) =>
            tableData.weeks[reportElement].daysInfo.length === index + 1 ? (
              <tr key={index} style={{ borderBottom: "none" }}>
                <td
                  style={{
                    padding: "10px 20px",
                    borderBottom: "none",
                    borderLeft: "2px solid #cccccc",
                    paddingLeft: "30px"
                  }}
                >
                  {row.dayDate}
                </td>
                <td
                  style={{
                    padding: "10px 20px",
                    borderBottom: "none",
                    textAlign: "center"
                  }}
                >
                  {row.response.toLowerCase() ===
                  reportsBackendResponses.notAsked ? (
                    <p
                      style={{
                        margin: "0",
                        padding: "5px 0",
                        backgroundColor: "#ffedbc",
                        border: "2px solid #cccccc",
                        borderRadius: "5px"
                      }}
                    >
                      {row.response}
                    </p>
                  ) : row.response.toLowerCase() ===
                    reportsBackendResponses.worked ? (
                    <p
                      style={{
                        margin: "0",
                        padding: "5px 0",
                        backgroundColor: "#cbfccb",
                        border: "2px solid #cccccc",
                        borderRadius: "5px"
                      }}
                    >
                      {row.response}
                    </p>
                  ) : row.response.toLowerCase() ===
                    reportsBackendResponses.absent ? (
                    <p
                      style={{
                        margin: "0",
                        padding: "5px 0",
                        backgroundColor: "#fbc7c5",
                        border: "2px solid #cccccc",
                        borderRadius: "5px"
                      }}
                    >
                      {row.response}
                    </p>
                  ) : row.response.toLowerCase() ===
                    reportsBackendResponses.refused ? (
                    <p
                      style={{
                        margin: "0",
                        padding: "5px 0",
                        backgroundColor: "#dddddd",
                        border: "2px solid #cccccc",
                        borderRadius: "5px"
                      }}
                    >
                      {row.response}
                    </p>
                  ) : (
                    <p
                      style={{
                        margin: "0",
                        padding: "5px 0",
                        border: "2px solid #cccccc",
                        borderRadius: "5px"
                      }}
                    >
                      {row.response}
                    </p>
                  )}
                </td>
                <td
                  style={{
                    padding: "10px 20px",
                    borderBottom: "none",
                    textAlign: "center"
                  }}
                >
                  {row.tutorHours}
                </td>
                <td
                  style={{
                    padding: "10px 20px",
                    borderBottom: "none",
                    textAlign: "center"
                  }}
                >
                  {row.creditValue}
                </td>
                <td
                  style={{
                    padding: "10px 20px",
                    borderBottom: "none",
                    textAlign: "center"
                  }}
                >
                  {row.attendence.toLowerCase() ===
                  reportsBackendAttendence.cancelled ? (
                    <p
                      style={{
                        margin: "0",
                        padding: "5px 0",
                        backgroundColor: "#ffedbc",
                        border: "2px solid #cccccc",
                        borderRadius: "5px"
                      }}
                    >
                      {row.attendence}
                    </p>
                  ) : row.attendence.toLowerCase() ===
                    reportsBackendAttendence.present ? (
                    <p
                      style={{
                        margin: "0",
                        padding: "5px 0",
                        backgroundColor: "#cbfccb",
                        border: "2px solid #cccccc",
                        borderRadius: "5px"
                      }}
                    >
                      {row.attendence}
                    </p>
                  ) : row.attendence.toLowerCase() ===
                    reportsBackendAttendence.noShow ? (
                    <p
                      style={{
                        margin: "0",
                        padding: "5px 0",
                        backgroundColor: "#fbc7c5",
                        border: "2px solid #cccccc",
                        borderRadius: "5px"
                      }}
                    >
                      {row.attendence}
                    </p>
                  ) : row.attendence.toLowerCase() ===
                    reportsBackendAttendence.notPlanned ? (
                    <p
                      style={{
                        margin: "0",
                        padding: "5px 0",
                        border: "2px solid #cccccc",
                        borderRadius: "5px"
                      }}
                    >
                      {row.attendence}
                    </p>
                  ) : (
                    <p
                      style={{
                        margin: "0",
                        padding: "5px 0",
                        border: "2px solid #cccccc",
                        borderRadius: "5px"
                      }}
                    >
                      {row.attendence}
                    </p>
                  )}
                </td>
                {row.studyValue ? (
                  <td
                    style={{
                      padding: "10px 20px",
                      borderBottom: "none",
                      textAlign: "left",
                      paddingLeft: "50px"
                    }}
                  >
                    {row.studyValue}
                  </td>
                ) : (
                  <td
                    style={{
                      padding: "10px 20px",
                      borderBottom: "none",
                      textAlign: "left",
                      paddingLeft: "50px",
                      color: "#CCCCCC"
                    }}
                  >
                    -&nbsp;-&nbsp;-
                  </td>
                )}
                <td
                  style={{
                    padding: "10px 20px",
                    borderRight: "2px solid #cccccc",
                    borderLeft: "2px solid #cccccc",
                    borderBottom: "none",
                    textAlign: "end"
                  }}
                >
                  {row.totalDayHours}
                </td>
              </tr>
            ) : (
              <tr key={index} style={{ borderBottom: "2px solid #cccccc" }}>
                <td
                  style={{
                    padding: "10px 20px",
                    borderBottom: "2px solid #cccccc",
                    borderLeft: "2px solid #cccccc",
                    paddingLeft: "30px"
                  }}
                >
                  {row.dayDate}
                </td>
                <td
                  style={{
                    padding: "10px 20px",
                    borderBottom: "2px solid #cccccc",
                    textAlign: "center"
                  }}
                >
                  {row.response.toLowerCase() ===
                  reportsBackendResponses.notAsked ? (
                    <p
                      style={{
                        margin: "0",
                        padding: "5px 0",
                        backgroundColor: "#ffedbc",
                        border: "2px solid #cccccc",
                        borderRadius: "5px"
                      }}
                    >
                      {row.response}
                    </p>
                  ) : row.response.toLowerCase() ===
                    reportsBackendResponses.worked ? (
                    <p
                      style={{
                        margin: "0",
                        padding: "5px 0",
                        backgroundColor: "#cbfccb",
                        border: "2px solid #cccccc",
                        borderRadius: "5px"
                      }}
                    >
                      {row.response}
                    </p>
                  ) : row.response.toLowerCase() ===
                    reportsBackendResponses.absent ? (
                    <p
                      style={{
                        margin: "0",
                        padding: "5px 0",
                        backgroundColor: "#fbc7c5",
                        border: "2px solid #cccccc",
                        borderRadius: "5px"
                      }}
                    >
                      {row.response}
                    </p>
                  ) : row.response.toLowerCase() ===
                    reportsBackendResponses.refused ? (
                    <p
                      style={{
                        margin: "0",
                        padding: "5px 0",
                        backgroundColor: "#dddddd",
                        border: "2px solid #cccccc",
                        borderRadius: "5px"
                      }}
                    >
                      {row.response}
                    </p>
                  ) : (
                    <p
                      style={{
                        margin: "0",
                        padding: "5px 0",
                        border: "2px solid #cccccc",
                        borderRadius: "5px"
                      }}
                    >
                      {row.response}
                    </p>
                  )}
                </td>
                <td
                  style={{
                    padding: "10px 20px",
                    borderBottom: "2px solid #cccccc",
                    textAlign: "center"
                  }}
                >
                  {row.tutorHours}
                </td>
                <td
                  style={{
                    padding: "10px 20px",
                    borderBottom: "2px solid #cccccc",
                    textAlign: "center"
                  }}
                >
                  {row.creditValue}
                </td>
                <td
                  style={{
                    padding: "10px 20px",
                    borderBottom: "2px solid #cccccc",
                    textAlign: "center"
                  }}
                >
                  {row.attendence.toLowerCase() ===
                  reportsBackendAttendence.cancelled ? (
                    <p
                      style={{
                        margin: "0",
                        padding: "5px 0",
                        backgroundColor: "#ffedbc",
                        border: "2px solid #cccccc",
                        borderRadius: "5px"
                      }}
                    >
                      {row.attendence}
                    </p>
                  ) : row.attendence.toLowerCase() ===
                    reportsBackendAttendence.present ? (
                    <p
                      style={{
                        margin: "0",
                        padding: "5px 0",
                        backgroundColor: "#cbfccb",
                        border: "2px solid #cccccc",
                        borderRadius: "5px"
                      }}
                    >
                      {row.attendence}
                    </p>
                  ) : row.attendence.toLowerCase() ===
                    reportsBackendAttendence.noShow ? (
                    <p
                      style={{
                        margin: "0",
                        padding: "5px 0",
                        backgroundColor: "#fbc7c5",
                        border: "2px solid #cccccc",
                        borderRadius: "5px"
                      }}
                    >
                      {row.attendence}
                    </p>
                  ) : row.attendence.toLowerCase() ===
                    reportsBackendAttendence.notPlanned ? (
                    <p
                      style={{
                        margin: "0",
                        padding: "5px 0",
                        border: "2px solid #cccccc",
                        borderRadius: "5px"
                      }}
                    >
                      {row.attendence}
                    </p>
                  ) : (
                    <p
                      style={{
                        margin: "0",
                        padding: "5px 0",
                        border: "2px solid #cccccc",
                        borderRadius: "5px"
                      }}
                    >
                      {row.attendence}
                    </p>
                  )}
                </td>
                {row.studyValue ? (
                  <td
                    style={{
                      padding: "10px 20px",
                      borderBottom: "2px solid #cccccc",
                      textAlign: "left",
                      paddingLeft: "50px"
                    }}
                  >
                    {row.studyValue}
                  </td>
                ) : (
                  <td
                    style={{
                      padding: "10px 20px",
                      borderBottom: "2px solid #cccccc",
                      textAlign: "left",
                      paddingLeft: "50px",
                      color: "#CCCCCC"
                    }}
                  >
                    -&nbsp;-&nbsp;-
                  </td>
                )}
                <td
                  style={{
                    padding: "10px 20px",
                    borderRight: "2px solid #cccccc",
                    borderLeft: "2px solid #cccccc",
                    borderBottom: "2px solid #cccccc",
                    textAlign: "end"
                  }}
                >
                  {row.totalDayHours}
                </td>
              </tr>
            )
          )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
```

---

### New Issues

**Issue #1:** some of the inline style (such as `backgroundColor` and `color`) is not being respected within the print preview

**Issue #2:** upon returning from the print modal back onto the page, you will notice a 2nd scroll bar has appeared on the right of the browser.

^ If anyone knows how to fix the two issues up above that would be of major help. Thanks.