# Browser Print a custom html in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting a HTML div from an API response and I want to send that response to the browser print command at a click of a button. Usually, window.print() works if you want to print the current page. But my current page has a different UI and the page I want to print is different. Any suggestion on how we can do this in React js?

Changing the current page and calling window.print() doesn't look like a feasible solution. The UI doesn't look that way. Any other solution appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider a package like https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-print

or check out this existing answer:
[How to print React component on click of a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135387/how-to-print-react-component-on-click-of-a-button)

Comment: The solution suggested in these links prints the component that are getting render, right? I am not rendering the HTML that I want to print. I am getting it from an API response.

Comment: using the previous stackoverflow answer you could append the response from the API to the element you want to print

Comment: There is no element that I want to print. I want to print the response I am getting form API.

Comment: I understand that - you could create an element and append the response to the element though and then modify the code in the old answer - should work. var content = createElement("tagName"); content.append(apiResponse); try that with the old answer I linked

Comment: Also I really don't know much about React - there's probably a better way to do this by bringing the API response into a component and then printing using something like react-to-print. If you can get the response data in the component then using a library that helps you print a component makes sense and would maybe accomplish what you're looking for in a a more React kind of way.

Answer (score 0):

use this media query to customise you print content

```
@media print { .printable-element { display: inline-block !important; //adjust accordingly margin: 0px !important; //adjust accordingly transform: scale(0.5) !important; //adjust accordingly height: 100%; //adjust accordingly page-break-before: avoid; } .hidden-on-print { display: none !important; } }
```

wrap your content with `printable-element` class name , whatever content you want to print . If you do not want to print any data use "hidden-on-print" class name to wrap your content