# Is there a way to print a specific part of a page with React?

Tags: html, reactjs, printing

I have a page, it's contain navbar, sidebar and Bill, how can to print only bill when click a button?

I'm attempt to using window.print() inside function, but it's print all page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print React component on click of a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135387/how-to-print-react-component-on-click-of-a-button)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by creating a new window, then I passed the html element that I wanted to print to the new window, after I found the css through the QuerySelector and added it to the head

p.s i used StyledComponents(css in js)

```
 var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=1000,width=1000');
    var css =document.querySelector('style[data-styled= "active"]').cloneNode(true);

    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>' + ""  + '</title>');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    
    mywindow.document.write(document.getElementById("print").innerHTML);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

    mywindow.document.close();
    mywindow.document.head.append(css);
    mywindow.focus(); 

    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();
```