# How to print a react element (using typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to print some data, generated based on some data I get from the database.

My plan was to use the code in this answer [How to print React component on click of a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135387/how-to-print-react-component-on-click-of-a-button)

```
var content = document.getElementById("divcontents");
var pri = document.getElementById("ifmcontentstoprint").contentWindow;
pri.document.open();
pri.document.write(content.innerHTML);
pri.document.close();
pri.focus();
pri.print();
```

but instead of *content.innerHTML* I would generate my own html

the problem is in the line

> var pri = document.getElementById("ifmcontentstoprint").contentWindow;

contentWindow does not exist. Am I missing some import or there is a new way to do this? (i'm using react 18.2.0, and typescript)

**edit:**
made some progress using:

```
const pri = (document.getElementById('ifmcontentstoprint') as HTMLIFrameElement).contentWindow
```

this fixes the typscript problem and now compiles and works for a simple string.
What if istead of printing some pre-existent element I want to render something on the go, like:

```
{props.list.map((item, i) =>
  <div className='ln-u-margin-bottom' key={i}>
    <Accordion className='ln-u-margin-bottom' data={item}/> 
  </div>)
 }
```

Is it possible to easily convert this to a string?

Comment: Do you want to print as  a string or a randered view?

Comment: Don't use `getElementById` in React. Use a Ref

Comment: I want to print a rendered view.
What is the correct code to use refs? I had some failed attempts

Comment: I had some progress doing const pri = (document.getElementById('ifmcontentstoprint') as HTMLIFrameElement).contentWindow

Now having trouble to render my inner componnets so they can be passed as a string into the write method

Comment: What do you mean by 'print a rendered view' ? Please add the desired output.

Comment: if instead of a string I pass something with actual react code like this:
{props.list.map((item, i) => <div className='ln-u-margin-bottom' key={i}> <Accordion className='ln-u-margin-bottom' data={item}/> </div>)}  (made up code, just as an example)

Comment: You could look at the other answers to that question; there are several...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print React component on click of a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135387/how-to-print-react-component-on-click-of-a-button)

Answer (score 0):

Use `react-to-print`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactToPrint from "react-to-print";

const Button = () => {
  return (
    <button style={{ background: "red", 
                     color: "white", 
                     padding: "10px" }}>
      Print this out!
    </button>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const componentRef = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const reactToPrintContent = React.useCallback(() => {
    return componentRef.current;
  }, [componentRef.current]);

  return (
    <div>
      <ReactToPrint trigger={() => <Button />} content={reactToPrintContent} />

      <div ref={componentRef}>
        /* Use the component that you want to print here. */
        <p style={{ background: "yellow", padding: "10px" }}>
          Print this component
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

#### Reference:

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-print
2. https://dev.to/ebereplenty/printing-in-react-made-easy-with-react-to-print-4b3k

Comment: This is just a copy of the marked duplicate....

Comment: And it's totally not TypeScript ready as OP requested.

Comment: And you're not doing anything with `componentRef`. This won't work

Comment: @0stone0, it works!You may try if you doubt.

Comment: What? Yea you fixed the things I mentioned. The UseCallBack is still not needed. And OP didn't asked for a library.