# how to create and print an invoice ticket for thermal printer with react.js and NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, invoice, ticket-system

I created an office application for managing a supermarket with Windev for a client but now he is asking me to make sure his application is connected to the internet so that he has remote access and controls everything from anywhere it turns out that. so I thought it was good to transform this application into a web application using React.js in front-end and NodeJs in Back-end but my biggest concern is to be able to set up the billing system

I would like my output state to look like this (same dimension, same shape)
[here is the image of a receipt that I want to have at the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oj4Iv.jpg)

Comment: You can talk to a thermal printer with WebUSB or plain ol' serial from Node. But your question is a bit broad and unclear all in all.

Answer (score -1):

Printing should not be as hard as you could think. In the internet browsers the API contains a print method which you can call from within react code:

```js
window.print();
```

Here is a more detailed answer already discussed on Stackoverflow:
[How to print React component on click of a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135387/how-to-print-react-component-on-click-of-a-button)

Comment: I thank you for your contribution,
I am not trying to print the entire window but only the customer orders which are already recorded in the Invoice table in my database

Comment: Okay, but then you could open a new tab with the content you want to print that structure. Or you print only data from a given div or something else [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div) If you want to print from within your Backend Code it is totally different to your question. Then you would not do the job with React JS but instead with your Backend Code language

Comment: I created a desktop application for the management of a supermarket with Windev for a client but now he asked me to ensure that his application is connected to the internet so that he has remote access and control everything wherever it is. so I thought it was good to transform this application into a web application using react.js but my biggest concern is being able to set up the invoicing system

Comment: Okay understood. But if you want to do a web application with React JS or something else you also need Code that runs on a server and will access your database. In this way you are using a classic three tier layer application [see here](https://medium.com/@kenslearningcurve/understanding-the-benefits-of-3-tier-architecture-7653f2225f5)